# Visual Studio npm install saving node_modules to solution folder

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2017

I am running Visual Studio 2017 Community with a Solution that has multiple projects. One of which is the Angular SPA with Core 2. In the Angular SPA project, if I run the command from the package command (with the SPA project being selected from the dropdown);

`npm install`

I get the error;

> WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\project\Project\package.json'

which makes sense as the project is actually

> 'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\project\Project\AngularSPA\package.json'

If I then right click the `package.json` and run the update packages command from the solution explorer, the node_modules folder with the npm packages is being installed to the parent directory too? i.e.

> 'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\project\Project'

Instead of

> 'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\project\Project\AngularSPA'

am I doing something wrong and is there a setting I should change here? (As I can copy the folder back to the AngularSPA folder but this seems a bit of a hack?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you start `nmp intsall` either from NuGet Package Manager Console or from built-in VS2019 Command Line -> Developer Command Prompt. Both bring solution directory as a npm working directory while you need a project directory.

There is a simple way to add a command prompt with the project directory as a working directory by adding Command Prompt as an external tool and select Project directory as Initial directory. More details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)

[image]